# Web Data connector in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

I am in need to develop a application which is used to access(get data from) web accessible resources like twitter,facebook,linkedIn,Salesforce etc. by using their appropriate REST API's. Can anyone please suggest me the pattern and architecture to design the logic of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are coupling with many online providers, there's increased chance that their API implementation changes overtime.

1. Think the API services as just any other Datasource. Implement the API service requester as a `Provider` class. Create an abstraction between this `Provider` and your actual process (where you use this data once you get it). This `Provider` will act as a source of data for the rest of the application. So any changes to API service will not affect your whole application.
2. Create separate Provider classes for each Online Platform  you need. Create `Model` that represents the data from API services and pass the `Model` object between `Providers` and `Consumers`.

Something like this

```
public interface IFBConnect {
    public FBData GetFBData();
    public bool PostFBData();
    //etc. etc
}

public class FacebookProvider : IFBConnect {
    public FBData GetFBData() {
        //call the webservice
        //parse the JSON to your model object
        return FBData
    }
}
```

Comment: May i please know the common method to write webservice? if I have a API's ....For example i have a API to get timeline in Twitter. how to use this API in C#?

Comment: @VinodKumar Are you asking how to send a request to twitter API service? or a skeleton method to call any webservice?

Comment: Hi Vishnu, I am asking about a skeleton method to call any webservice.

Comment: @VinodKumar see a sample method here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/consuming-json-rest-or-restful-web-services-response-using-net-c-sharp-client1 . Remember this question is Off-topic with respect to SO.

Comment: Thanks Vishnu.it helps me.